# JPA native query get different result than executed directly on DB

Tags: jpa, nativequery, jparepository

I have this query in my jpa repository

```
@Query(value = """
        SELECT DISTINCT a.*
        FROM V_APP_STORICO_STATI a
        WHERE a.ID_RAGGR_ACCRED = :idRaggr AND
        lower(a.cod_stato) <> lower(:cos) AND
        a.storicizzato = 1
        ORDER BY a.data_stato desc
        """, nativeQuery = true)
List<VistaPerStoricoAccreditamenti> findByIdRaggrAccredAndStoricizzato(@Param("idRaggr") Long idRaggr, @Param("cos") String cos);
```

if i execute the query directly on the DB i get this result

[image]

if the query is executed by jpa repository i get different values

[image]

the fifth element value is different. What is the problem?
why jpa is unable to get correct results?

Comment: The queries not seem to be identical. In "direct" query contains commented section `--lower(a.cod_stato) <> lower(:cos)`

Comment: ouch, sorry i posted the screenshot in which i was trying different soluction... i will post the correct screenshot without  section commented.... but in fact if i comment the same section in jpa  repository i get same wrong results